# How to rewrite a block's form variable with a node's custom field in Drupal 8

Tags: youtube, drupal-8

I want to rewrite a Variable set in a Block Form with a Field that is set in individual nodes of a certain Content Type.  In Drupal7 I was able to hack the module PHP and everything worked well but in Drupal8 not so well.  The block never refreshes by rewriting a new field.

I feel I must be missing some built-in solution with Views and a preprocess hook without hacking at the module.

The module I am working to integrate is the YouTube Video Transcript module (https://www.drupal.org/project/transcript). The Transcript module follows exactly the setup described in the Drupal article "Creating custom blocks" (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-blocks).

OLD DRUPAL7 HACK
at \transcript\Plugin\Block\TranscriptBlock.php

```
function transcript_show() {
...
  $node = menu_get_object();
  $video_id = $node->field_myfield_id['und'][0]['value'];
```